# Include only one brand in the ecommerce reports for a single affiliate in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, ecommerce, filtering, page-views

I am trying to create a view for a partner that is selling their products on our site.

I assumed that filtering their brand name with "E-commerce Item Name" would result in the same report as filtering their brand name by "Product" in "E-commerce" > "Product Performance" report, but it didn't.

How should I approach creating a view which would include only e-commerce data related to their products?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view with an Include Only Filter by Name/Code or anything else of the article, and use a regular expression to identify only their products. It can work if your products have in their name or code a unique identifier that distinguish your competitor's brand name.

There's also an alternative: you can create a scheduled report (via email) based on a segment.
You can create a segment going to Advanced -> Conditions, selecting Brand product and putting your affiliate brand product name.
If that's not enough for getting all the traffic he's interested in, you can use the OR operator and insert new conditions, like visitors coming from a particular referrer.